# NMOS level 8 Ltspice model of 2SK4177

Tags: ltspice, nmos, model

After downloading a model from https://www.onsemi.com/design/resources/technical-documentation?rpn=2SK4177, I deleted everything apart from what was between .MODEL and ), so I ended up with a xxx.txt file containing this:

```
.MODEL 2SK4177 NMOS (                                LEVEL    = 8             
+VERSION  = 3.2            TNOM     = 27             TOX      = 1.0E-07       
+VTH0     = 2.70           K1       = 3.86           K2       = -0.04         
+NLX      = 4.70E-07       DVT0     = 3.12           DVT1     = 0.09          
+DVT2     = -0.01          U0       = 600            UA       = 1.04E-10      
+UB       = 1.00E-21       VSAT     = 1.84E06        A0       = 0.66          
+AGS      = 1.00           A1       = 0              A2       = 1             
+RDSW     = 9.00E05        PRWG     = 0.0E00         WR       = 0.92          
+WINT     = 0              LINT     = -7.20E-08      VOFF     = 0.00          
+NFACTOR  = 0.64           CIT      = 0              CDSC     = 2.40E-04      
+CDSCD    = 0              ETA0     = 0.14           DSUB     = 0.96          
+PCLM     = 0.01           PDIBLC1  = 0.10           PDIBLC2  = 1.20E-03      
+DROUT    = 0.96           PSCBE1   = 1.00E11        PSCBE2   = 1.00E-05      
+PVAG     = 0.01           DELTA    = 0.03           NGATE    = 1.0E19        
+MOBMOD   = 1              NQSMOD   = 0              NOIMOD   = 1             
+CAPMOD   = 3              XPART    = 0.5            CGSO     = 6.00E-11      
+CGDO     = 1.00E-10       CGBO     = 0              CGSL     = 0             
+CGDL     = 6.00E-09       CKAPPA   = 1.20           CF       = 0             
+CLC      = 3.0E-09        CLE      = 0.8            DWC      = 0             
+DLC      = -1.00E-06      NOFF     = 3.66           VOFFCV   = -0.40         
+ACDE     = 1.0            MOIN     = 15             CJ       = 2.00E-03      
+MJ       = 0.35           PB       = 0.65           JS       = 1.00E-03      
+NJ       = 1.30           XTI      = 3.0            IJTH     = 0             
+KT1      = -0.6           UTE      = -0.6           PRT      = 3.00E06       
+AT       = 3.3E04         )
```

In Ltspice I used an .include statement for the xxx.txt file, added an nmos symbol with VALUE = 2SK4177. When I run the simulation, the model is accepted but the MOSFET current is just 50uA (not 100mA as expected and proven by a different MOSFET from the standard Ltspice library).

[image]

What is wrong? I wonder if the level 8 model works in Ltspice. If not, how can I change the model to make it work? I haven't found any other model for 2SK4177.

Answer (score 4):

When you deleted that "everything" else you also deleted the information about the width, length, and area (and some others):

```
* Temp = 27 deg                                                               
* W    =   228740 E-6 m                                                       
* L    =      3.0 E-6 m                                                       
* AD   =   228740 E-12 m2                                                     
* RG   =        9 ohm                                                         
* RB   =    0.045 ohm
```

If you'll <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>RClick</kbd> on the symbol and add in one of the `Value2`, `SpiceLine`, or `SpiceLine2` this line:

```
w=228.74m l=3u ad=228.74n`
```

you'll see that the drain current is ~90 mA. Don't forget that, when you picked a model from the database (I'm guessing `STW11NM80`, the highest Vds), those transistors are `VDMOS`, a bit different than the `NMOS/PMOS`, which are meant to be monolithic MOSFETs. BTW, don't forget that the `VDMOS` has a builtin antiparallel diode, the `NMOS` doesn't. Well, you could say "technically", but, really...

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks! I wonder why RG and RB are not known by Ltspice if I add them on SpiceLine too (I didn't want to lose any info in the model). I'd love to have a VDMOS model but don't know how to extract the parameters needed from the supplier-provided model.

Comment: @Hyp  I would use an `nmos4` symbol and add those two resistors as discrete components (as shown in the PDF).  Level=8 (or BSIM3) models don't have `RB` and `RG` parameters.  Speaking of which, it's bizarre they supply a BSIM3 model for a power MOSFET.  They're usually supplied as subcircuits to properly model the gate-drain capacitance and gate charge of the vertical topology.  You could screw around with making your own VDMOS model but I don't know if it's worth it.  I suggest try what they supplied and see how far it gets you first.

Comment: @SteKulov That's what puzzled me, too: I thought the `.model` was part of a composite `.subckt`, but there's not even a hint of a body diode (which is shown in the datasheet).

Comment: The monolithic MOS models in SPICE do have PN junctions as shown by [Fig 4-6 and Eq 4-31 & 4-32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iitwj.jpg).  I believe the same holds for BSIM3 and the parameters for the junctions in that case are `JS`, `NJ`, and `IJTH`.  The external `RB` is for adding diode ohmic resistance.  See Chapter 9 of [the BSIM3 manual](https://ngspice.sourceforge.io/external-documents/models/bsim330_manual.pdf) for more details on that.

Comment: @SteKulov I seem to remember Mike saying that they're modelled and connected slightly different than an anti-parallel diode, as shown in the LTspice manual (*LTspice > Circuit Elements > M. ..*), even if connecting the substrate to the source would achieve the same thing. That's why I said "technically". Something about an actual diode model used in there, that's why it borrows the `Is, Cjo, ..` parameters. But don't quote me, I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Yah, that's all true. I guess I shouldn't compare apples and oranges. The Level 1/2/3 models are the only ones that the textbook Figure is valid for, and it's different than a VDMOS which has the body diode path going around both Rd and Rs (instead of just Rs). BSIM3 model has no explicit Rd and Rs and uses a per area sheet resistance Rsh, so I don't know exactly what the deal is. Most subcircuit power MOSFET models I come across use a LEVEL=3 and an explicit body diode overriding the built-in one. Anyway, my point is that I'm more skeptical of the gate charge stuff than the diode.